# Can a video uploaded to Firebase Storage be streamed at other user's convenience?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Apparently, you can stream an mp3 file that was uploaded to Firebase storage. But, how would one go about this for a video file?

Firebase docs says the way to retrieve a video is to download it, but I don't want to "download" it.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42057701/4815718) to a related question indicates _Firebase Storage doesn't support video streaming_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by treating the firebase URL as a regular URL.

```
    String str = "FIREBASESTORAGE_VIDEO_URL";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);

    videoViewLandscape.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoViewLandscape.requestFocus();
    videoViewLandscape.start();
```

Comment: whenever it is done playing a particular video after few seconds I'm getting a popup saying that can't play the video.  Can you please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44447813/7004388)