# How to play a video in a VideoView that is stored in FirebaseStorage?

Tags: android, video, firebase, firebase-storage, android-videoview

I need to know how I can play a file that is in the firebase, for the moment I only know how to do that with "Glide" but that only serves for photos. The point is that with a "Dialog" the videos are uploaded to the Firebase, and then I do not know how to "rescue" them in a video view in my recyclerView as I do with "Glide"

This is how I do it with Glide but only works with photos:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                        .getReference(model.getPostImageUrl());


                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(storageReference).into(viewHolder.postDisplayImageView);
```

And I do not know how to do it with videos

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Video from Firebase Storage to videoView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053822/load-video-from-firebase-storage-to-videoview)

Comment: @BobSnyder this is a stream of a video, not a load