# Has Firebase a library for download videos that are on Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, video, thumbnails, firebase-storage

Has Firebase a library to download videos that are on Firebase Storage? I want to put the video inside a VideoView. I mean a library like Picasso for images but in this case for videos.

As an example:

with images is -> Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageUri).into(ImageView);

exist something like:

Library.with(ctx).load(videoUri or videoURL).into(VideoView); ?

and if answer is yes, how can I get the thumbnail of that video?

PD. I have the URL of the video in Database as a value of a child("video") and uploaded it with taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

Sorry for my english and thx for every help!

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42053822/4815718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say your download url is `LINK`.

```
VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(LINK));
video.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really works! How can I do it if I want to use it inside a ViewHolder? I don't know if it's ok asking you here or do I have to start another question?