# m3u8 file which stored in Firebase storage does not play on web players

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I have stored m3u8 file in firebase cloud storage and this is URL for m3u8 file

```
[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testing-musicoi.appspot.com/o/MediaContent%2F240p%2F240_out.m3u8?alt=media&token=0f81947b-1df0-4333-ae67-bdf21b4c49cc]
```

This URL works perfectly when I use VLC Player on my computer but when I try the same link with web players like this [HLS media player](https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test?format=hls&manifest=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2Ftesting-musicoi.appspot.com%2Fo%2FMediaContent%252F1080p%252F1080_out.m3u8%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3Daefafcfd-3b73-49f9-b96f-44807013a90d) it does not work. Moreover, I want to know This m3u8 URL would not work with Android Exoplayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web player relies on [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), that allows scripts on one domain to access data from another domain. This fails, because your origin domain does not allow access from other domains.

You need to configure the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow `bitmovin.com` (and other domains) to access your files.

Edit your `firebase.json` and add or change the `hosting` section:

```js
"hosting": {
  "headers": [ {
    "source": "**/*.*",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value": "*"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

See [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Honestly, I did not know about this and again thank you for your effort.  As I understand, I only need to do this for if I'm going to play media on the website, But what about player like android Exoplayer?

Comment: @IsuruBandara, I don't know about Exoplayer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463115/android-exoplayer-is-it-possible-to-use-exoplayer-to-stream-video-from-firebase) which might be of your interest:

> First create an exoplayer in your xml file

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

> "I have set the height as 0 cuz im gonna fix the height programmatically later then declare simple SimpleExoPlayer in your activity as player."

```
 SimpleExoPlayer player;
```

> "Then in you follow these steps"

```
//declare your PlayerView 

final PlayerView playerView = mview.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

//your database ref

        final StorageReference storageReference =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/Post_Video/"+ video + ".mp4");


 player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(MainActivity.this);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        playerView.getLayoutParams().height=550;
        playerView.getLayoutParams().width=950;

        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {


                BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
                TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
                ExoPlayer exoPlayer = (SimpleExoPlayer) ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(MainActivity.this);
                Uri video = Uri.parse(uri.toString());
                DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("video");
                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(video,dataSourceFactory,extractorsFactory,null,null);
                playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
                exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);

            }
        });
```