# Displaying Videos in Recycler View

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to display videos which I downloading from firebase to play in a Recycler View. But for some reason it wont play and it will just show a black screen. The video download URL from firebase is correct , so thats not the issue.

This is what shows up in the logcat:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/creatives-4ebde.appspot.com/o/All_Uploads%2FDesign%2FVideos%2F1562657263842.mp4?alt=media&token=d08f8a8f-903f-4dd7-82c0-4b7bbc183567
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1663)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1493)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1410)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1102)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1074)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1098)
    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:412)
    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2200(VideoView.java:83)
    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:694)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:725)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:151)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1088)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2743)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7595)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

This my Recycler View Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter2  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

Context context2;
List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;


public RecyclerViewAdapter2(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context2 = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items2, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(UploadInfo.getImageURL());
    Log.d("TAGGG" , ""+uri);
    holder.videoView.setVideoPath(uri.toString());
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public VideoView videoView;
    public TextView imageNameTextView;
    public SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
    public SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //videoView = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);
        imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    }
}
}
```

I am using a VideoView to play the video.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
holder.videoView.setVideoURI(uri.toString());
```

instead of

```
holder.videoView.setVideoPath(uri.toString());
```

Comment: it doesnt make a difference. Same result

Comment: read this article may this help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057701/5370550