# How do I render Firebase Storage videos on a website?

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase, video, server

From other SO answers (e.g [Firebase Storage: Play back of a video url directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480449/firebase-storage-play-back-of-a-video-url-directly)), I understand that Firebase does not support video streaming so I can't just provide a `<video>` element my URL and expect it to playback the resource. As such, how would I go about displaying videos which are stored in Firebase Storage on my website?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase storage support only files download. so you need to use [getDownloadUrl here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url):

This is how I do it in React:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/lazy';
import { storage } from "../../firebase/fbConfig"

const VideoView = (props) => {
    const [vedio, loadVedio] = useState("");
    const vedioLoader = info => {
        
        storage.ref().child(VIDEO_REF).getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function (event) {
                var blob = xhr.response;
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();
            loadVedio(url)
            console.log(url)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

   return (
    <ReactPlayer id="myVedio"
                            url={vedio}
                            width='100%'
                            height='100%'
                            playing={true}
                            controls={true}
                            volume={1}
                            progressInterval={5000}
                            pip={true}
                        />
)
}
```