# Show a video on onboard screen without need to keep video file on apk

Tags: android, performance

I have a doubt about how to show an intro video on the onboarding screen of our application.

When the user opens the app for the first time we'll show an onboarding screen presenting a background video about us and the user can read mini texts about the app and select if they need to do log in or sign in.

The problem is, we don't want to keep a video file inside the APK just to show a single time per user, and I don't know if adding youtube SDK to the project just for this feature is the best solution.

Comment: Use Firebase Cloud Storage, AWS, or any other cloud storage as per your preference.

Comment: download the video from the storage you mean? there's any way to reproduce when the video is downloading, like youtube? or i need to download the entire video and reproduce to the user

Comment: I haven't explored video streaming features using cloud storage. Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37865482/9636037

Comment: thank you! i'll take a look about this

Comment: you dont need to download, just provide the mp4 url to the player, be it android media player or exoplayer