# Best way to store video for a Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, aws-mediastore

I'm working on a Flutter App and want to include some Tutorial Videos, which all Users have unlimited access to, so they can rewatch it any time. The Videos will be about 10-20 files with 1-5 minutes length.

I guess these amount of data will be too big to be stored as app assets, so I researched a bit and found Firebase Storage and AWS MediaStore.

Thoughts on this ? Or any recommendations - I don't want to run in the wrong direction.

Comment: Hello Mixdy aws MediaStore or s3 Storage will be good option. Also use cache video player for improved performance

Comment: You might use `HLS` with firebase if you want to store video which is of length 10 or more, if you wish to  beacause i have gone through some sources than they suggest `HLS`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865482/firebase-storage-video-streaming

Comment: Also this https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/flutter-video-upload-firebase-storage-hls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest hosting them on a private S3 bucket with a public CloudFront distribution in front of it for best performance.  HLS file groups are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of an obvious answer but my suggestion is that you place these videos on YouTube and mark them as Unlisted. This way you can build the URLs of these videos into your Flutter application and then load those videos with a web_view plugin that you can find on pub.dev.