# How to upload video chunks to server and download them in real time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm creating an iOS app where I want a user to be able to live stream a video, however, users who join the live stream after it starts, start watching the stream from the beginning instead of live (I will also add functionality that allows the user watching to skip ahead and then be able to watch live).

I have looked at many third party streaming options such as Agora, Twilio, Vimeo, etc, however, I don't believe they meet my needs as I need users who join the live stream to start watching from the beginning and not live.

I have explored continuously uploading small video chunks to something like firebase storage, and then continuously reading those chunks for users watching the stream. However, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870706/13731318 , this is to very efficient and leads to a substantial lag.

Does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this that leverages third parties?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the HLS protocol to implement this.
HLS allows starting to watch from the beginning or not. That is controlled by the settings.
I am not sure about uploading because I think it has to be implemented on the server-side more.